# How to configure amazon SNS in Cordova mobile for receiving push notification

Tags: cordova, amazon-web-services, push-notification, ionic-framework, amazon-sns

I am developing Cordova application using ionic framework. I want to use amazon-sns service for push notification.

I had configure amazon sdk for browser in application. But  `AWS.config.credentials.get` only return success object with data when execute mobile application in browser,

But it is giving error in android mobile. It is showing network error thought network is connected and working.

And `sns.createPlatformEndpoint` method is also giving credential error you can see both error in screenshot.
[image]

Here is code-snap as well

```
.run(function($cordovaPush,$rootScope) {

  var registerForSNS = function(gcmId){
    var params = {
      PlatformApplicationArn: 'my amazon arn', /* required */
      Token: gcmId, /* required */
      CustomUserData: 'STRING_VALUE'
    };

    sns.createPlatformEndpoint(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) 
        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      else{
          console.log(data.EndpointArn);
          alert(data.EndpointArn); 
       }              
    });
  } 


  AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
  AWS.config.update({
    credentials : new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
      IdentityPoolId: 'my Identity pool ID'
     })
  });
  var sns = new AWS.SNS();
  AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err) {
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
    } else{
      console.log(AWS.config.credentials);
      registerForSNS();
    } 
  });

  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){

     var androidConfig = {
      "senderID": "my sender id",
    };
    $cordovaPush.register(androidConfig).then(function(result) {
      // Success
      alert(JSON.stringify(result));
    }, function(err) {
      // Error
      alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    })

    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function(event, notification) {
      switch(notification.event) {
        case 'registered':
          if (notification.regid.length > 0 ) {
            alert('registration ID = ' + notification.regid);
            registerForSNS(notification.regid); 
          }
          break;

        case 'message':
          // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
          alert('message = ' + notification.message + ' msgCount = ' + notification.msgcnt);
          break;

        case 'error':
          alert('GCM error = ' + notification.msg);
          break;

        default:
          alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
          break;
      }
    });    
  }, false);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get actual problem why it was not calling from ionic mobile app. But i remove all the plugin and then try and it start working. I get little bit idea that some plugin has add or remove some network related permission in app